# Submit score problem in LeaderboardsClient class

Tags: google-play-games

I intend to introduce a leaderboard in my turnbased dice game. When reviewing the Google Play Games API, I found that only the highest score was updated in the submitScoreImmediate(...) method:

Description in API:
The score is ignored if it is worse (as defined by the leaderboard configuration) than a previously submitted score or the same player.

For many games, this implementation is sufficient. However, there are also games (in special competitions with 2 players / teams) where both an increase and a reduction of the score is required, e.g. chess (Elo rating) or a dice game.

Is there an optional solution to this problem?
What other possibility of realization do I have?

Comment: I have now found a solution with two leaderboards: bestScore and worstScore. By a win, I add to bestScore with a loss on worstScore. To get the current score from a player I only have to subtract worstScore from bestScore. In order to get a leaderboard of all players I have to perform the above procedure for each player and then create a new sorted leaderboard.
I will start with the realization, let's see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because once you submit the score to a leaderboard, you cannot take away from it.

For your case, the best way would be to submit the score once you know the score cannot go down. This might happen at the end of the game, at the end of a level, etc. Depending on the game you can choose where the best place to submit the score would be.

If you wanted to, you could even have two separate leaderboards. One for "highest score ever" and a "highest score after finishing" so the "highest score ever" could be updated constantly and the "highest score after finishing" would be updated after finishing. This is just an idea and may be confusing for some players. In some games, this may be a cool addition, though.

It's also worth noting that there are also daily and weekly high scores. So even if a call to submitScore isn't the highest, it still may be used for daily or weekly.

Comment: The main problem is that it is not possible to reduce the score with the submitScoreImmediate(...) method. All other methods of the class LeaderboardsClient would be OK.
A confusion of the players (multiple leaderboards) I would like to prevent.

Comment: @KarlSchreiner because it isn't possible to reduce the score with any calls to a LeaderboardsClient, you will have to only call submitScore or submitScoreImmediate only when you know that the raw score value you give to those methods will not go down (usually after the game has ended). What do you mean by "all other methods of the class LeaderboardsClient would be OK"?

Comment: These are the get leaderboard and the load scores methods of the class LeaderboardsClient, as described in the API. But in all four submit score methods you can not update a smaller score.

Comment: @KarlSchreiner it's not possible to update a score that you've already submitted to make it a "worse" score. You can change the ordering so that "smaller is better." But from what you described it sounded like bigger scores are better but, just because you have a high score at a point in the game, that score may still go down by the end of the game.